# SimpleDateFormat showing a.m./p.m. instead of AM/PM

Tags: kotlin, simpledateformat

I am trying to use SimpleDateFormat to display the time as `12:00:00 AM`. Here is what I am doing:

```kotlin
val timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a")
val timeString = timeFormat.format(Date(transaction.time))
```

According to [these docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html?hl=pt-br) `a` should show AM/PM

timeString come out in the format: `12:00:00 a.m.`

How can I make it show AM instead of a.m.?

Comment: `AM/PM` may change according to default locale. i.e `PM` is `오후` in Korean. Try to call `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US)` before time formatting to see if formatting suits your needs.

Comment: @ocos Thanks, setting the Locale to US did fix the issue

Comment: Glad to help you. Check first locale for this kind of questions: number formating, date formatting ...

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) or their Kotlin equivalents.

Comment: @ocos Setting the default locale for the entire JVM and all programs running in it? That could easily create more problems than it solves. Just set it on the formatter: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US)`.

Comment: The `PM` in your link is an example. It says *Examples* over that column. This particular example seems to be taken from the US locale (or another locale that uses AM and PM). Other locales offer other examples.

Comment: @OleV.V. `Locale.setDefault` was just a hint to see if his problem was about the locales. Of course, as you mentionned in your comment, one should not set the locale whenever he wants. I should be more careful in my comment. Thanks.